# Web scraping with rvest. Returning as NA

Tags: web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am quite new to web scraping and I am trying to scrape the 5-yr market value from a five thirty eight site linked here (https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/carmelo/kyrie-irving/). This is the code I am running from the rvest package to do so.

```
kyrie_irving <- 
read_html("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/carmelo/kyrie-irving/")

kyrie_irving %>% 
html_node(".market-value") %>% 
html_text() %>% 
as.numeric()
```

However the output looks like this:

```
> kyrie_irving <- 
  read_html("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/carmelo/kyrie-irving/")
> kyrie_irving %>% 
+   html_node(".market-value") %>% 
+   html_text() %>% 
+   as.numeric()
[1] NA
```

I'm just wondering where I am going wrong with this?

EDIT: I have tried using RSelenium to do this and still get no value returned. I am really lost as to what the problem is. Here is the code:

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L,  browser = "chrome")

remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/carmelo/kyrie-irving/")

elem <- remDr$findElement(using="css selector", value=".market-value")
elemtxt <- elem$getElementAttribute("div")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rselenium works, you just need to change the last line code and you can get the result.

```
elem$getElementText()
[[1]]
[1] "$136.5m"
```

By the way, the result is a string, so you need to remove **$** and **m**, then you can parse it into a number.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I'm a bit new to web scraping so I'm still learning the ins and outs.